# Data Type casting issue in asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I have to save result for my linq in cache and then retrieve it. But I am getting an error with the following code:

```
public PartialViewResult showall()
{
    //initially getting data from DB
    var task1 = from r in _db.Task1
            where r.Status == true
            orderby r.Post_Date descending
            select new
            {
             id = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)r.Task1_ID),
             dt = r.Post_Date,
             typ = "Task1"
            };
    HttpContext.Cache.Insert(key: "Task1Data",
                         value: task1, 
                         dependencies: null, 
                         absoluteExpiration: DateTime.Now.AddHours(5), 
                         slidingExpiration: System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration
                         );
    var task1Cache = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["Task1Data"] as IQueryable);
    var task1list = from a in task1Cache.Cast<Task1data>()
                select new
                {
                 id = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)a.Task1_ID),
                 dt = a.Post_Date,
                 typ = a.typ 
                }; 
    var task2 = from r in _db.Task2
            orderby r.Post_Date descending
            select new
            {
             id = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)r.Task2_ID),
             dt = r.Post_Date,
             typ = "Task2"
            };
    HttpContext.Cache.Insert(key: "Task2Data",
                         value: task2, 
                         dependencies: null, 
                         absoluteExpiration: DateTime.Now.AddHours(5), 
                         slidingExpiration: System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration
                         );
    var task2Cache = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["Task2Data"] as IQueryable);
    var task2list = from a in task2Cache.Cast<Task2data>()
                select new
                {
                 id = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)a.Task2_ID),
                 dt = a.Post_Date,
                 typ = a.typ 
                }; 
    var listc = task1list.Union(task2list);
    var q3 = (from r in listc.Cast<Totaldata>() 
                 select new
                 {
                     mix = r.typ + "~" + r.id
                 }).ToList();
    return PartialView("~/Views/Ex/_ShowAll.cshtml", q3);
}
```

I get the following exception at the last line:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast the type 'Anonymous type' to type 'Models.Task1data'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

```
public class Task1data
{
    public double Task1_ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Post_Date { get; set; }
    public string typ { get; set; }
}

public class Task2data
{
    public double Task2_ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Post_Date { get; set; }
    public string typ { get; set; }
}

public class Totaldata
{
    public double id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Post_Date { get; set; }
    public string typ { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are selecting anonymous type with `select new` in your controller and in your view you probably have specifieid `Task1data`  as model, hence the error.

Comment: that's not the case. No function is working for q3. like q3.count() its giving exception typenotsupported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten rid of task1data and task2data casts because they aren't necessary (and not correct) and just used the totaldata class.  Also, I've created a new type to store the results called `something` because you can't pass anonymous types around.

```
public something() { public string mix {get;set;}}
public PartialViewResult showall()
{
    //initially getting data from DB
    var task1 = from r in _db.Task1
            where r.Status == true
            orderby r.Post_Date descending
            select new Totaldata
            {
             id = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)r.Task1_ID),
             dt = r.Post_Date,
             typ = "Task1"
            };
    HttpContext.Cache.Insert(key: "Task1Data",
                         value: task1, 
                         dependencies: null, 
                         absoluteExpiration: DateTime.Now.AddHours(5), 
                         slidingExpiration: System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration
                         );
    var task1Cache = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["Task1Data"] as IQueryable<Totaldata>);
    var task1list = from a in task1Cache
                select new Totaldata
                {
                 id = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)a.Task1_ID),
                 dt = a.Post_Date,
                 typ = a.typ 
                }; 
    var task2 = from r in _db.Task2
            orderby r.Post_Date descending
            select new Totaldata
            {
             id = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)r.Task2_ID),
             dt = r.Post_Date,
             typ = "Task2"
            };
    HttpContext.Cache.Insert(key: "Task2Data",
                         value: task2, 
                         dependencies: null, 
                         absoluteExpiration: DateTime.Now.AddHours(5), 
                         slidingExpiration: System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration
                         );
    var task2Cache = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["Task2Data"] as IQueryable<Totaldata>);
    var task2list = from a in task2Cache
                select new Totaldata
                {
                 id = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)a.Task2_ID),
                 dt = a.Post_Date,
                 typ = a.typ 
                }; 
    var listc = task1list.Union(task2list);
    var q3 = (from r in listc 
                 select new something
                 {
                     mix = r.typ + "~" + r.id
                 }).ToList();
    return PartialView("~/Views/Ex/_ShowAll.cshtml", q3);
}
```

Comment: On second hand, there is so much wrong with this code that I can't fix it without knowing a lot more.  The datatype you are storing in the cache appears to be of type `Totaldata`, you pull it back out, and then cast it to a different (incompatible type), then access members (Task1_ID) that doesn't exist on the data in the cache.  You'll need to rectify those issues yourself.  Perhaps you were trying to change the datatype you put in the cache?  Neither your original code nor mine should compile and run, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem boils down to you playing fast and loose with types here. First, when you pull out the tasks from the database, you're selecting them into an *anonymous object*, i.e. `select new { ... }`. The result now is an `DbQuery<[AnonymousType]>`. Which is what you're setting in the cache. Then, when you pull it out, you're trying to cast it to `IQueryable`. That should be fine, but now you don't even have the dynamic nature of an anonymous type any more.

Next, you cast the whole thing yet again to `Task1Data`. That's not going to work for two reasons. First, you have a collection of items here, which you'll never be able to cast to a non-collection class like your `Task1Data`. Second, even if you cast it more correctly to something like `IEnumerable<Task1Data>` the members of the items in the collection don't match up to properties in `Task1Data`. They're not even remotely the same thing, so you can't ever cast back to `Task1Data`.